# Use ob_start and ob_end_flush to include CSS in a global file

Tags: php, ob-start

I have a `globals.php` file included in every file on my site. I'd like to include on this file a `CSS` file `globals.css`.

The problem is that if I add the CSS in `globals.php` and then include it on all file, I get some errors like:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]:
Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /...)
in /... on line 4
```

or when using

```
header('Location: ....');
```

Is there a better-more appropiate solution than using `ob_start` at the top of `globals.php` and `ob_end_flush` at the bottom of the same file, or is this method the right way to operate?

globals.php

```
<?php
ob_start();

//some costants and functions
?>

<head>
    <link href="/css/globals.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<?php
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're flushing the buffer at the end of the globals script, turning off the buffering, so if you had something like

```
header('...'); // this will work, no output yet
include('globals.php'); // flushes buffers, stops buffering, starts output
header('...'); // fails with "headers already send"
```

if you're doing any header() calls AFTER you include the globals file, then globals should **NOT** be flushing the buffers.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that... So how can I include a css file in globals.php?

Comment: What you're doing is fine. just **REMOVE** the ob_end_flush() stuff in globals. That's where the problem kicks in.

Comment: Ok, but if I call ob_start() after globals.php without calling ob_end_flush at the end of globals.php, will it fails?

Comment: you can call ob_start() as many times as you want. each will just open a new buffer, and exiting the script will automatically flush/send any buffers still open. technically you never HAVE to call end_flush() yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! (I do not understand why my question received '-1'. To me, it appears as a properly question! Maybe I don't know this site well enought)

Comment: I still have a problem: on the Javascript alert box I get always `<head><link ...></head>', because of the AJAX reply. How can I prevent that? Thank you

Comment: because your code structure is wrong, then. instead of putting css headers into a 'globals' file, it should be in whatever file outputs your site's boilerplate `<head>` section.

Comment: So the only solution is to include the `global.css` file in every document's `<head>`? This is what I wanted to avoid... But if it's the only solution....

Comment: no, but don't output the css header unless it's necessary. e.g. if you're doing ajax responses, you don't need to be dumping out an `<html>...</html>` container...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sessions, make sure to call `session_start` before doing anything else. The error message means that you're trying to call `session_start` after you've already done some output or other things.